# Resizing and rearranging component controls using code/ IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, interface-builder

Is it possible to resize and rearrange UI components (say segmented controls, buttons, labels, etc) when these are created using IB?

I need to rearrange/resize few UI components on a button click on iPad screen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You will need to create `IBOutlet`s for the UI components you are interested in, then you can adjust the properties you are interested in (UIView's frame property)

`IBOutlet`'s are created in the *.h file for you View controller.

```
IBOutlet UIView * view;
```

Then you can <kbd>control</kbd> click and drag from the file owner (in xib) to the UI element. (or right click and drag)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  Implement the `viewDidLoad` method in your controller and set the frame to whatever you wish for your views and controls so long as you've attached them to an outlet.

Example:

```
self.myCustomView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: See my answer :).  There, you can both resize it and modify its origin all from one property.  See this link: [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5).  If you are inquiring about hooking it up to an outlet, see answer by @Maudicus.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may also access them by their tag.
If you assign them unique tag numbers in IB, then in your code, you can search within subviews of your view and find them by `viewWithTag` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial position of the components in IB, hook up the elements with IBOutlets and on the button click move them in code. I don't think you can rearrange them in IB.

For a cool effect you can use [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:] to move whatever components you need